# Recursive code for a tree function?

Tags: c, recursion, tree, nodes

I have a function that returns the first node of a tree,

```
node* primeiro(tree r){
    while(r->left != NULL){
        r = r->left;
    }
    return r;
}
```

BTW, the percuss is made in order. So the function returns the leftmost leaf of the tree and the function presumes that the tree is not empty. How can I implement this in a recursive way?

```
 node* primeiro (tree r) {
    while (r->left != NULL) {
     r = primeiro (r->left); 
    }
    return r;
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: Define "_not working_". Is it crashing, not compiling, giving you an unexpected result, nothing at all?

Comment: `while` --> `if`

Comment: What should `primeiro(NULL)` return?

Comment: It was returning nothing

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in using `while`. You need simple [recursion termination condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination).

```
node* primeiro (tree r) {
    if (r->left != NULL) {
        r = primeiro (r->left); 
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using condition **r->left != NULL** for while loop, check it for true or false. (that will be base condition for the termination of recursion).

Comment: What does this add to the prior answer?

Comment: The question was unanswered, when i saw it.

Answer (score 0):

When we speak of "recursive functions", we usually mean "functions that use recursion to loop"...

Both of your functions are using `while` to loop. You should focus on transforming that `while` loop into a recursive function call.

Consider this loop:

```
int fubar(int x) {
    while (x > 0) {
        x--;
    }
    return x;
}
```

It transforms into this:

```
int fubar(int x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return fubar(x - 1);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Notice how similar the two are. The differences are:

- You're changing `x` not directly but by passing a different value of `x` in
- Your loop test is in an `if` statement, not `while`...
- Again, you're not looping using `while`; instead you should be calling `fubar` again, passing in a new value and returning its result.

Important note: There could be [significant benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) to ensuring every recursive function call is followed immediately by a return (without any intermediate calculations required).

Answer (score 0):

When iteration is being replaced with recursion, it may be easier to derive the right code by beginning with the infinite recursive loop:

```
node* primeiro(tree r){
    /* What goes in the recursive loop body? */
    return primeiro(r);
}
```

You can now ask under what would the next value of the iteration, and when does the loop stop. The next value is pretty straight forward.

```
node* primeiro(tree r){
    /* When does the recursive loop stop? */
    r = r->left;
    return primeiro(r);
}
```

From the `while` loop logic, the loop stops when `r->left` is `NULL`. At that point, you would return `r`.

```
node* primeiro(tree r){
    if (r->left == NULL) return r;
    r = r->left;
    return primeiro(r);
}
```